# elixir ecto: test has_many association

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd, elixir, ecto

I am a newbie in elixir, so don't be too harsh
I have following models:

```
defmodule MyApp.Device do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "devices" do
    field :name, :string
    belongs_to :user, MyApp.User

    timestamps
  end
end

defmodule MyApp.User do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "users" do
    field :name, :string
    has_many :devices, MyApp.Device

    timestamps
  end
end
```

How do I test that user has many devices in an elegant way. For instance

```
  test "registration generates user with devices" do
    changeset = Registration.changeset(%Registration{}, @valid_attrs)
    registration = Ecto.Changeset.apply_changes(changeset)
    user = Registration.to_user(changeset)
    IO.puts "#{inspect user}"
    # assert device is inside the user
  end
```

Comment: What's that Typi you're referencing?  Typi.User and Typi.Device? I mean I'd guess there's a Typi module somewhere but is it yours?

Comment: You may find the contents of this conversation from the Elixir Talk Google Group worthwhile reading too: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/elixir-ecto/BKpLf092dWs

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Changed to MyApp :) forgot to rename stuff. I tried to hide the name

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Thanks for the link, good guide lines

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't something like this work?

```
  test "registration generates user with devices" do
    changeset    = Registration.changeset(%Registration{}, @valid_attrs)
    registration = Ecto.Changeset.apply_changes(changeset)
    user         = Registration.to_user(changeset)
    IO.puts "#{inspect user}"
    # assert device is inside the user
    assert Repo.all(from d in Device, where: d.user_id == ^user.id) != []
  end
```

Comment: Ye, but `to_user` does not persist anything to db. So I just wanted to test the structure

Comment: What thought about is `assert [Map.merge(%MyApp.Device{}, @valid_attrs)] == user.devices`, however it merges stuff not related to the struct